# jquery add class to div with specific z-index

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, z-index

I have a couple of divs with unique z-indexes. Now I want add a couple of classes to a div with a specific z-index. Let's say the z-index of this div is 5.

All the divs a positioned in a main div with the class `.main-stack` and all have the class `.card` There are several `.main-stack` divs. All need to be checked if the div with the specific z-index is there or not. If it's found, some classes should be added to that div.

I have the following half-working code:

```
$('.main-stack').each(function () {
    if ($(this).css('z-index', '5')) {
        $('.main-stack .card')
            .addClass('ui-front')
            .removeClass('flipped')
            .removeClass('ui-draggable-disabled')
            .removeClass('ui-droppable-disabled')
            .draggable({
                disabled: false
            })
            .addClass('top-card');
    }
});
```

The problem with this code is that it adds the classes to all the divs instead to just to the one with z-index = 5

What am I missing here?

Comment: `if($(this).css('z-index', '5')) {` will set the `z-index`, to get and compare use `if($(this).css('z-index') == 5) {`

Comment: You can add multiple classes by `addClass` and remove multiple classes by `removeClass`, CODE: `$('.main-stack').each(function () {
    if ($(this).css('z-index', '5')) {
        $('.main-stack .card')
            .addClass('ui-front top-card')
            .removeClass('flipped ui-draggable-disabled ui-droppable-disabled')
            .draggable({
                disabled: false
            });
    }
});`

Comment: @Tushar, Please write this as an answer!

Comment: @ntgCleaner I've added answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if($(this).css('z-index', '5')) {` will set the `z-index` of the element and `css` will return the jQuery object, so it'll always evaluate to `true`.

To retrieve and compare the `z-index` use

```
if($(this).css('z-index') == 5) {
```

---

For performance gain, you can add multiple classes with `addClass` and remove multiple classes with `removeClass`

```
$('.main-stack').each(function () {
    if ($(this).css('z-index') == 5) {
        $('.main-stack .card')
            .addClass('ui-front top-card')
            .removeClass('flipped ui-draggable-disabled ui-droppable-disabled')
            .draggable({
                disabled: false
            });
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks, also @ebilgin both same answer, the toss for final answer went to Tushar :)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery `.css()` function can get 2 parameters. If you pass **1** parameter, you will call get function. If you pass **2** parameter you will call set function.

If you change your code like below, you can get a working one.

```
$('.main-stack').each(function () {
    if ($(this).css('z-index') == '5') { // Change here.
        $('.main-stack .card')
            .addClass('ui-front top-card')
            .removeClass('flipped ui-draggable-disabled ui-droppable-disabled')
            .draggable({
                disabled: false
            });
    }
});
```

You can get a more information about `.css()` here.

http://api.jquery.com/css/